# Very large heap size when reading large files

Tags: java

I have an ascii file that consist 180 columns of digits and about 60000 rows. File size is ~80MB.

I need to read that file into 2d array with size 180x60000.

File structure example:

> gsrv01:   946177  946061 ..[many columns]..   8359486 8359485 0 end total 184
>
> .. [ many rows ] ..
>
> gsrv01:   945998  946259 ..[many columns]..   8359489 8359487 1 end total 184

When I'm reading this file I'm getting usage of memory about 800MB. I'm using data from this file in GUI application, so total amount memory getting over 1200MB. This is unacceptable.

Am I doing reading right? How can I reduce memory usage?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadBigData {

public static void main(String[] args){
    
    String pathFilename = "E:\\data\\8.txt";
    
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    new ReadBigData(pathFilename);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();

    long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
    double dur = (double) duration/1000000/1000;
    System.out.println("Elapsed: " + dur + " sec.");

    try {
        System.in.read(); //to wait after execution.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
}

public ReadBigData(String pathFilename){
    
    //list for containing data
    List<List<Double>> dataTableList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
    
    Pattern spacePattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+"); //split by whitespace or tab
    
    String regex = "^gsrv01:\\s+(.*)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+end total.*";//. -- any symbol, * -- repeated zero or more times.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pathFilename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            
            Matcher matches = pattern.matcher(line);
            while(matches.find()){
                
                //slow!!!!!!!!!!!!
                
                String columnsStr =  matches.group(1);
                List<String> columnsList = Arrays.asList(spacePattern.split(columnsStr, 0)); //fast
                
                List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
                for (String str : columnsList) {
                    list.add(Double.parseDouble(str));
                }
                dataTableList.add(list);
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //list to array
    Double[][] dataTable = new Double[dataTableList.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTableList.size(); i++) {
        List<Double> row = dataTableList.get(i);
        dataTable[i] = row.toArray(new Double[row.size()]);
    }
    
}
}
```

[File link[80MB]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxa81qklzS9BdUk1T0NsX1hObjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use `double`, not `Double`. A `double` uses 8 bytes of memory. A `Double` uses 20-32 bytes.

Comment: Good idea, thank you.

Comment: Do you really need all that data at once in your GUI? I think it can be optimized better if you tell us what you need to do with the data (display it in a table or something)?

Comment: At least I need display data in chart, one or two selected columns.

Comment: Do you have an example? Since you can't really display thousands of numbers in a chart, I guess you do some calculation on the data? Maybe you're able to extract the data you really need in a stream and not save all data in a large array, if you really have to save memory that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [API for processing unquantifiable sets of data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). Depending on the amount of numbers, you may want to remove the nested stream and just use a for-loop.

```
public static  List<double[]> read(String pathFilename) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^gsrv01:\\s+(.*)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+end total.*");

    try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathFilename);
        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream)) {

        return reader.lines()
                .map(pattern::matcher)
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .map(matcher -> matcher.group(1))
                .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
                .map(strings -> Arrays.stream(strings)
                        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                        .toArray())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(read("8.txt").size());
}
```

This method parsed 59292 lines of numbers from the 80Mb file you attached in less than 3 seconds on my 6-year-old laptop

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Working definitely faster than my implementation (2.7sec vs 4.5sec). But still using memory ~750MB. I don't know, maybe not possible to reduce this amount.

Comment: @AndreiSh  The file alone and the arrays in memory total slightly less than 200mb. Allocating large arrays slows down the garbage collector (I think). Although I'd recommend doing your own research as I can't help much more - I'm not very well versed in performance and profiling. Also note that you can try to add `.parallel()` when starting the stream if order doesn't matter to you.  It completed even faster when I used that

Comment: This is a succinct way of writing the same code (performant), however it does not solve or target the original problem of Space.

Comment: @SunilSinghal there isn't any "problem" with the space. It takes up exactly what it needs to load it into memory. He should terminate the stream using `limitTo(/* some number */)`, and then continue with the InputStream/Scanner later by opening it again into another stream if he wants to cut down on memory. Some things like the size of `double`s are constant, but copying `Lists` and `Arrays` around is where the real problem is. This solution improves it in the only way possible

Comment: @PrestonGarno Exactly and that is what i pointed out in my answer: 2nd point below. Implicit List expansion behind the scenes when adding elements in a list created without capacity

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `List<List<>>`, the unnecessary RegEx, and use `double` instead of `Double`, something like this:

```
public double[][] readBigData(String pathFilename)
{
   // list for containing data
   final List<double[]> dataTableList = new ArrayList<>();
   final Pattern spacePattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+"); //split by whitespace or tab
   try (final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                              new FileInputStream(pathFilename))))
   {
      final String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
      while (line != null)
      {
         final String[] fields = spacePattern.split(line, 0);
         final int l = fields.length;
         // Check the format
         if ("gsrv01:".equals(fields[0]) && "end".equals(fields[l-3]) &&
             "total".equals(fields[l-2]))
         {
            final double[] list = new double[l-5];
            for (int i = 1; i < l-4; ++i)
            {
               list[i-1] = Double.parseDouble(fields[i]);
            }
            dataTableList.add(list);
         }
      }
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   // list to array
   return dataTableList.toArray(new double[dataTable.size()][]);
}
```

Also should not process data in a constructor...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This code for now doesn't work because of something endless... Fields.length always equals 3. I will think about make it working later.

Answer (score -1):

Another small observation i had besides what already have been listed above:

1. Replace the below statement

   ```
   List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
   ```

   with

   ```
   List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(columnsList.size());
   ```

   This way, you can prevent re-allocation of List objects on expansion
2. Use Arrays instead of List. With this you will prevent copying of data from array to list and vice versa

   ```
   Double[] coll = new Double[columnList.size()];
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
   ```

Comment: You're missing what's most likely the cause of his performance problems http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: @PrestonGarno Can you point to the code statement where you think Boxing/Unboxing is happening? Don't think that there is any. Also will be happy to know the reason behind down voting my answer.
When list grows, its gonna create another list with double the capacity and might be wasting the memory there

Comment: Yeah it's to bad Java doesn't allow primitive types in generic types, but there is not much you can do other than using simple arrays...

Comment: @xander using the java.util.Stream API to parse to a double and collect to an array then add the result to a `List<double[]>` doesn't do it. It leaves the responsibility up to the `Stream` framework designers, who've more likely than not thought about this problem. Much different than iteratively adding to a `List<Double>`

Comment: @PrestonGarno yes but in your solution with the stream auto boxing is also happening here `.mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)` (returns a `List<Double>`) and then you convert it to an `double[]`. I just mean that it is a general problem with generics in the language and type erasure.

Comment: @PrestonGarno My 2nd point does not suggest to use List<double[]>
Rather it suggested to use double[] or Double[] instead of List<Double>

Comment: @xander `mapToDouble` returns a `DoubleStream`, not a `List<Double>`. You're right about boxing/unboxing happening even with a stream, however, the solution using streams isolates it to 1 spot (`Double::parseDouble`). Streams do not make `List`s, they just represent lazily evaluated data

Comment: @SunilSinghal I wasn't talking about your solution then.  But since you defended yourself by saying you "suggested to use double[] or Double[] instead of List<Double>", I'm going to assume you don't fully understand autoboxing in Java

Comment: @preston I'll be happy to learn from you. Why do you think that there will be autoboxing if an array instead of a list is used